# US visitor visa for Canadian Permanent Residents

Tags: usa, visa, pr

I read on another forum that Canadian PRs are scrutinized/denied US visitor (and other) visas more than others. Why is this the case? If I am a Canadian PR I'm less likely to overstay in the US since I will eventually return to Canada (or so the logic should go?).

Comment: Did the statement on the other forum have any evidence to back it up?  The thing about forum posts is that people can say things that aren't correct. Another possibility: Canadian PRs can also become visa exempt by naturalizing; perhaps the greater refusal rate (if it exists) can be attributed to factors that [prevent people from taking Canadian citizenship](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-citizenship/become-canadian-citizen/eligibility.html#criminal).

Comment: No there was no proof more like anecdotal heresay. Sometimes they do have weight to them though.

Comment: I can't find any useful statistics (for example refusal rate by visa-issuing post, which would also include Canadian residents who aren't PRs, but might at least shed some light on the question).  All I could find was rates by nationality, which says nothing about where the application was submitted, where the applicant resides, or what immigration status the applicant has in that country.

Comment: can you post a link to this particular forum? We can't really make a determination without reading that.

Comment: Recent immigrants to any country have an elevated risk of a US  visa refusal. They've shown a recent willingness to move, but not yet spent enough time in their current residence to demonstrate permanent ties there, so they have a harder time overcoming the presumption of immigrant intent. This should be equally true in any country but in Canada, where most people live very close to the US, it may be that a higher number of quite recent immigrants find a reason to apply for a US visa before they have established themselves adequately to satisfy the consular officer.

Comment: @Dennis, thank you this makes a lot of sense.